# Simple One Finger Touch Event

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile, touch

Does anyone know how I can implement a single Touch Event. A simple, one finger touch event, not multiple gesture or anything... Just a simple one finger touch.

I want to learn how to do this instead of doing LeftButtonMouseUp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to any control:

#### XAML

```
Tap="Control_Tap"
```

#### CodeBehind

```
private void Control_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // Tap Logic
}
```

[Here is a link to the Gesture cheat sheet](http://adamkinney.com/blog/2010/09/23/windows-phone-7-gestures-cheat-sheet/)